# azure api management returning internalservererror via put rest request

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I'm currently trying to add a Logger via a REST request via Postman. Here's my test request:

```
PUT https://myapimgt.management.azure-api.net/loggers/my-test-logger?api-version=2015-09-15

{
  "type" : "AzureEventHub",
  "description" : "Sample logger description",
  "credentials" : {
    "name" : "my-eventhub",
    "connectionString" : "sb://my-eventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test-access;SharedAccessKey=bDotPrTAb7loNlCvtXjH8KeM2q4jS3+R4P1x78A4kqs="
    }
}
```

The request above returns the following error object:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InternalServerError",
    "message": "Request processing failed due to internal error.",
    "details": null
  }
}
```

Any idea what the problem is or how I can debug?  I'm able to GET /loggers without issue through a different Postman request.

Comment: Just heard that a fix for this error message has been made and is in the process of being incorporated into our next release.  Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your connection string is missing "Endpoint=" at the begining, so the correct payload should be:

```
{
    "type" : "AzureEventHub",
    "description" : "Sample logger description",
    "credentials" : {
        "name" : "my-eventhub",
        "connectionString" : "Endpoint=sb://my-eventhub-ns.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=test-access;SharedAccessKey=bDotPrTAb7loNlCvtXjH8KeM2q4jS3+R4P1x78A4kqs="
    }
}
```

We will need to check why this error is not reported correctly and fix it.